# Appium(Script Recording Tool)

Tags: appium

I have created an automation script for android device (Android Version 4.4).I want to record my whole script in a form of video.I surrfed on the net and found 2 toools (OpMirror Sender and Reciver), Second is (AZ Screen Recorder) ..But problem is that the AZ Screen recorder works for android version 5 and higher. On the other hand i have read the reviews  for the OpMirror , and i found that it is not relible ..So Can anybody suggest me some tool for the same or provide me with a Url from where i can get it

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this if you have adb on your computer. Connect the devices and start recording with:

```
adb shell screenrecord --verbose /sdcard/video1.mp4
```

On mac control + c to stop, then pull the video off the device with:

```
adb pull /sdcard/video1.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below link it will work.
 [Download Droid @ screen](http://droid-at-screen.org/download.html)

---

Use monitor.bat file in the tools folder.
Launch it and select the device . Device option select Screen Record.[image]

Comment: i have Downloaded Droid @ screen.. but there is no option to make video

Comment: You should record the windows screen  because it will give mirror of the operation which we do in real device or emulator. Kindly download any record application for windows and capture it.